# SQL server 2008 login issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

Hi I created a new login SQL server authentication in SQL server 2008, however I am unable to login with that user.

Getting an error like ,

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to (local).

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Login failed for user 'sa'` means that connection to server was established, but server refused it under certain circumstances, such as:

- Wrong password
- Sql server uses only Windows Authentication (needs server restart)
- In your Connection String you ask to connect to specified DB, which is not exists
- sa login is Disabled or Denied to access sql engine

Comment: Ok 1st condition password is correct for me, third i had given for default DB master, it does exist, now how to check the 2nd one ?

Comment: Thanks Oleg the second one was the problem, correct it and got another error,TITLE: Connect to Server
---------------------------

Cannot connect to (local).

------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

Comment: The above error ha gone, now again getting old error, All the three pointed out problems are now solved, yet getting the smiler error!!

Comment: See if your sa login is granted access, check the 2nd point once more, restart the sql server, the error is the same - about 'sa' login?

Comment: From the Event log I got this,Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: Check your connection string - or publish it here, without passwords, of course. Looks like you use trusted connection

Comment: Sorry from where I can get it, i am trying to log into SQL server 2008 management studio, not from any program!!

Comment: Then in Event Log it is regarding something else, let's go to the chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6263/discussion-between-oleg-dok-and-jithu)

Comment: Thanks for doing it using Team viewer!! :)

Answer (score 2):

> **User Action**
>
> 1. If you are trying to connect using SQL Server Authentication, verify
>      that SQL Server is configured in Mixed Authentication Mode.
> 2. If you are trying to connect using SQL Server Authentication, verify
>      that SQL Server login exists and that you have spelled it properly.
> 3. If you are trying to connect using Windows Authentication, verify
>      that you are properly logged into the correct domain.
> 4. If your error indicates state 1, contact your SQL Server
>      administrator.

From [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456)

Should this not help try troubleshooting this issue following [these steps.](http://sql-articles.com/articles/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-login-failed-error-18456/)

Comment: Thanks OD the first one was the problem, correct it and got another error,TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to (local).

------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

Comment: The above error had gone, now again getting old error, All the three pointed out problems are now solved, yet getting the smiler error!!

Comment: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: try to open SQL Server Management Studio and right click the instance in question, go to Properties -> Connections -> Check "Allow remote connections to this server".

Comment: Hi OD thank you for spending time with this, Oleg shutdown and restarted again, Working great now